# What is wrong with this simple FindRoot?

Tags: equation-solving

```
z := 0.0000000000001

LE = NDSolve [{(2/ξ) θ'[ξ] + θ''[ξ] +  θ[ξ]^3 == 0, θ[z] == 1, θ'[z] == 0}, 
              θ[ξ], {ξ, z, 10}]; 

Plot[ Evaluate[{θ[ξ], θ'[ξ], θ''[ξ]} /. LE], {ξ, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {ξ, θ}]

f[ξ_] = Evalute[θ[ξ] /. LE]; 

Manipulate[NSolve[f[n]], {n, 0, 7}]

FindRoot[f[ξ], {ξ, 7}]
```

And I get, FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {Evalute[{-0.00431221}]} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {[Xi]} = {7.}. >>

Why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  The edit window  help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.

Comment: Because you spelled `Evaluate` wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
z = 0.0000000000001;

le = NDSolve[{(2/x) t'[x] + t''[x] + t[x]^3 == 0, t[z] == 1, 
     t'[z] == 0}, t[x], {x, z, 10}][[1, 1]];

led = NestList[D[#, x] &, le, 2];

Plot[Evaluate[{t[x], t'[x], t''[x]} /. led], {x, z, 10},
 AxesLabel -> {x, t},
 PlotRange -> {-0.5, 1.1},
 PlotLegends -> {"t(x)", "t'(x)", "t''(x)"}]
```

[image]

```
Clear[f];

f[x_?NumericQ] := Evaluate[t[x] /. le]

Off[NSolve::ifun];

NSolve[f[x] == 0, x][[1]]
```

> {x -> 6.89685}

```
FindRoot[f[x], {x, 6}]
```

> {x -> 6.89685}